# What replacement options are there for heightForRowAtIndexPath in a UITableView?

Tags: ios, uitableview, dynamic, row-height

tableView `heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` is deprecated according to the iOS docs.  It mentions using rowHeight instead, but that property is for all rows.  I want to flow the rows' height versus the content's (`UILabel`) varying size.

Is several custom cell styes my only other option besides `heightForRowAtIndexPath`?

Comment: Do you have a link to where it says it's deprecated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Sorry to tell you that...but it isn't deprecated ;)

EDIT: only thing they are saying is if you have very big tables (1000+ cells) it's better to use rowHeight because of performance issues.

Comment: Good, because it works great.  I just hate using anything titled deprecated.